# Kronecker product preserves the conjugacy relation?

Tags: gr.group-theory, finite-groups, algebraic-groups, classical-groups, conjugacy-classes

Let $G =$ PGL$_{n}(\textbf{C})$ and $T$ be the image in $G$ of the subgroup of the invertible diagonal matrices of $\operatorname{GL}_{n}(\textbf{C})$. Let $A$ and $B$ be two elementary abelian $2$-subgroups in $T$ of the same rank.

The Kronecker product $\otimes I_{2}$ embeds $A$ and $B$ in $H$ = $\operatorname{PGL}_{2n}(\textbf{C})$. If $A$ and $B$ are not conjugate in $G$, will $A\otimes I_{2}$ and $B\otimes I_{2}$ not be conjugate in $H$? Intuitively, they are not conjugate in $H$ but I'm not sure of tools to tackle it. Maybe subgroup conjugacy is an equivalent relation and $\otimes I_{2}$ reserves it?

Edit:
Some thinking made based on the input in the comment.
If $A$ and $B$ are not conjugate in $G$, and we assume $A\otimes I_{2}$ and $B\otimes I_{2}$ are conjugate, attempt to get a contradiction. Since $A\otimes I_{2}$ and $B\otimes I_{2}$ are both block diagonal matrices with blocks $I_{2}$ and $-I_{2}$, if there always exists a "block permutation matrix" with each block $I_{2}$, then we're done. But I'm not sure about the existence of such a "block permutation matrix"... Any hints would be appreciated.

Comment: Here is your tool: Two diagonal matrices are conjugate to each other if and only if the elements on the diagonal are permutations of each other (because these are the eigenvalues of these matrices, hence invariant under conjugation).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If $A$ and $B$ are elementary abelian $2$-subgroups of $\mathrm{PGL}_n(\mathbf C)$ of rank $r$ then they lift uniquely to elementary abelian $2$-subgroups of $\mathrm{GL}_n(\mathbf C)$ of rank $r+1$ (take all lifts $a$ of elements of $A$ such that $a^2 = 1$), so let us assume $A, B \le \mathrm {GL}_n(\mathbf C)$ to begin with.

Consider a representation $\rho:C_2^r \to \mathrm{GL}_n(\mathbf C)$ with character $\chi$. Decompose $\chi$ into irreducible characters: $\chi = w_1 \chi_1 + \cdots + w_m \chi_m$. Here $\chi_1, \dots, \chi_m : C_2^r \to \{\pm1\}$ and $w_1, \dots, w_m$ are positive integers. Two representations $\rho$ and $\rho'$ are equivalent (conjugate) if and only if they have the same character, so equivalence classes of representations $\rho:C_2^r \to \mathrm{GL}_n(\mathbf C)$ are in bijection with maps $w: D \to \mathbf N = \{0,1,2,\dots\}$ such that $\sum_{\chi \in D} w(\chi) = n$, where $D \cong C_2^r$ is the dual group of $C_2^r$ (the group of characters $\chi : C_2^r \to \{\pm1\}$ with pointwise product as the group operation). Here $w(\chi_i)$ records the multiplicity of an irreducible character $\chi_i$ in $\chi$. The representation is faithful if and only if the support $\mathrm{supp}(w) = \{\chi : w(\chi) > 0\}$ of $w$ generates $D$.

To get conjugacy classes of embedded copies of $C_2^r$ we must further quotient $\{w:D \to \mathbf N \mid \langle \mathrm{supp}~w\rangle = D\}$ by the action of $\mathrm{Aut}(C_2^r) \cong \mathrm{GL}_r(2)$.

In any case the Kronecker product just sends $w$ to $2w$, so the conjugacy relation is preserved.

Comment: I really appreciate your input. May I ask about the definition of the dual of a group and the support of a map? Also, I'm not quite sure how $w$ maps elements... And how do we sum up the $w$ so the sum is $n$? Sorry for the trouble. Thank you!

Comment: I added some words. I hope it helps.

Comment: Thank you for the added words which helped me a lot. Could you please point me to a proof of "the representation is faithful iff the support of $w$ generates $D$"?

Comment: Also, I don't quite get this: to get the conjugacy classes in $\operatorname{PGL}_{n}(\textbf{C})$, we quotient $\{w:D \to \mathbf N \mid \langle \mathrm{supp}~w\rangle = D\}$ by the action of $\mathrm{Aut}(C_2^r) \cong \mathrm{GL}_r(2)$. Could you please elaborate a bit more? Thank you very much!

Comment: For the first: if $\chi = w_1 \chi_1 + \cdots + w_m \chi_m$ then $\rho$ is equivalent up to conjugation to a diagonal representation with $\chi_1, \dots, \chi_m$ entries (and the appropriate multiplicities). Clearly this is faithful iff $\ker \chi_1 \cap \cdots \cap \ker \chi_m = 0$, which is equivalent to $\mathrm{supp}(w)$ generating $D$.

Comment: For the second: without quotienting we have a parameterization of faithful embeddings $\rho : C_2^r \to \mathrm{GL}_n(\mathbf{C})$ up to conjugacy. But we want to consider two of these to be the same if they have the same image. Therefore we need to quotient by the action of the automorphism group of $C_2^r$. This quotienting has nothing to do with $\mathrm{PGL}$.

Comment: Thank you for your patience. For the first, do you mean the intersection of the kernels of the reps is trivial instead of zero? Thx.

Comment: That's what I mean, yes.

Comment: Sorry, I am still digesting. For the second, you are saying, before quotienting, there could be two different parameterizations of faithful reps yielding a same embedded image? Would you please give a short example to make it concrete? Like a Klein 4 in $\operatorname{GL}_{4}$? I'd appreciate your help.

Comment: Consider two maps $C_2^2 \to T \le \mathrm{GL}_2(\mathbf C)$. Here let us identify $C_2$ with $\{\pm1\}$. The first map is $(x, y) \mapsto \mathrm{diag}(x, y)$. The second is $(x, y) \mapsto \mathrm{diag}(x, xy)$. The characters are $x+y$ and $x+xy$, so the representations are not equivalent. But they have the same image.

Comment: Yes! I've just worked out a similar example to see this! And I've finally got most of your answer. I'll keep digesting. Not sure what time it is where you are, but really appreciate your patience!

Comment: I think this is the last question: My start point is two nonconjugate elementary abelian 2-subgroups $A,B$ in $PGL_{n}$, they lift uniquely to $\dot{A},\dot{B}$ in $GL_{n}$, then $\dot{A}⊗I_{2},\dot{B}⊗I_{2}$ in $GL_{2n}$, at last, $A⊗I_{2},B⊗I_{2}$ in $PGL_{2n}$. So it boils down to $A\sim B$ iff $\dot{A}∼\dot{B}$, it I'm correct? But I am not sure how to see from the right to the left. Intuitively, it seems correct.  $\sim$ means conjugacy relation.  Thx!

Comment: Yes $A$ lifts uniquely to $\dot A$ and conversely $A$ is just the image of $\dot A$ in $\mathrm{PGL}$, so the correspondence is bijective, and $A \sim B$ iff $\dot A \sim \dot B$.

Comment: I'm sorry, I just realized this: has the condition that $A,B\leqslant T$ been used anywhere in the argument?

Comment: No. It's redundant, because any finite abelian subgroup of $\mathrm{GL}_n(\mathbf{C})$ is diagonalizable, i.e., conjugate to a subgroup of $T$.